# confusion with a manipulation in a equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

[image]

In line(5), I dont understand why the $O(k^2)$ and $O(h^2)$ became linear in the lhs. Is it because

$$ k C + O(k^2) = O(k) $$

where $C = \frac{u_{tt}}{2} $ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have first order terms in $k$ and $h$. Provided enough regularity, equation (5) shows that
$$
\tau_j^n = O(k) + O(h) + O(k^2) + O(h^2) = O(k)+O(h).
$$

Comment: What do you mean by regularity? Also, does $O(k) + O(k^2) = O(k)$??

Comment: Some regularity is necessary because of the term $u_{xx}$ appearing in the formula. And yes, $O(k)+O(k^2)=O(k)$. Imagine a quantity of the order of $10^{-8}$, its square would be of the order of $10^{-16}$. Wouldn't you say that $10^{-8} + 10^{-16} \approx. 10^{-8}$?